# Socket module, how to send integer

Tags: python, sockets

I am reading in a value on the client side and want to send that to a server side so it can check if its prime. I'm getting an error because the server is expecting a string

**server side**

```
import socket

tcpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsocket.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 8000) ) 

tcpsocket.listen(2)
(client, (ip,port) ) = tcpsocket.accept()

print "received connection from %s" %ip
print " and port number %d" %port

client.send("Python is fun!")
```

**client side**

```
import sys
import socket

tcpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

num = int(raw_input("Enter number: "))

tcpsocket.connect( ('192.168.233.132', 8000) ) 
tcpsocket.send(num)
```

`Error: must be string or buffer, not int.`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: don't convert `raw_input` into `int`

Comment: "Error is must be string or buffer, not int." that's why

Comment: I think you mean `buffer`.

Comment: convert the `int` back to a string: `str(num)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tcpsocket.send(num)` accept a `string`, [link to the api](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html?highlight=send#socket.socket.send), so don't convert the number you insert to `int`.

Answer (score 13):

Never send raw data on a stream without defining an upper level protocol saying how to interpret the received bytes.

You can of course send integers in either binary or string format

- in string format, you should define an *end of string* marker, generally a space or a newline

  ```
  val = str(num) + sep # sep = ' ' or sep = `\n`
  tcpsocket.send(val)
  ```

  and client side:

  ```
  buf = ''
  while sep not in buf:
      buf += client.recv(8)
  num = int(buf)
  ```
- in binary format, you should define a precise encoding, `struct` module can help

  ```
  val = pack('!i', num)
  tcpsocket.send(val)
  ```

  and client side:

  ```
  buf = ''
  while len(buf) < 4:
      buf += client.recv(8)
  num = struct.unpack('!i', buf[:4])[0]
  ```

Those 2 methods allow you to realiably exchange data even across different architectures

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.7.2

```
>>>i_num = 123
>>>b_num = i_num.to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=False)
>>>b_num
b'{\x00'
>>>reverted = int.from_bytes(b_num, 'little', signed=False)
>>>i_num == reverted
True
```

Answer (score 2):

**I found a super light way to send an integer by socket:**

```
#server side:
num=123
# convert num to str, then encode to utf8 byte
tcpsocket.send(bytes(str(num), 'utf8'))

#client side
data = tcpsocket.recv(1024)
# decode to unicode string 
strings = str(data, 'utf8')
#get the num
num = int(strings)
```

**equally use encode(), decode(), instead of bytes() and str():**

```
#server side:
num=123
# convert num to str, then encode to utf8 byte
tcpsocket.send(str(num).encode('utf8'))

#client side
data = tcpsocket.recv(1024)
# decode to unicode string 
strings = data.decode('utf8')
#get the num
num = int(strings)
```

Comment: If you send the number 11 and then immediately send 12, how will the receiver know whether you sent two numbers: 11 and 12 or one number: 1112? You should either send byte strings with separators or a properly framed binary protocol as @serge-ballesta suggested above. Usually the binary protocol is easier to manage. Construct a fixed length header (that can then specify the exact length of any variable-sized data fields), and make sure the peers send and receive exactly the specified number of bytes (IOW, don't just `recv(1024)` and assume you got the entire thing -- that is unreliable.)